# How can I get rid of these white borders around my carousel?

Tags: html, css

here's the issue I added a shadow around my carousel and I just saw that I got that white border around it, how could I get rid of it ?
Here's a screenshot of the issue : [My issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM4AM.jpg)

Here's the code :

```css
.carousel-text h1{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 165px;
    text-align: center;
}
.carousel {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 0px 15px;
    max-width: 55%;
    margin: auto;
}

.carousel-inner {
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/Softee/pen/RwLaJye
I made it simple so it's ugly but we can see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue is you have two separate `border-radius` values. On your image you're using `15px` and on your parent `(.carousel)` you're using `20px`. Make these changes to solve your problem.

```css
.carousel {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```